# WP8 C# communicate with web server over SSL

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have been struggling the entire day to get my C# Windows Phone 8 to talk to my PHP web server over SSL (HTTPS). My server is implemented in such a way that it reads the GET parameters sent to it and then echos an appropriate response. It already works fine in the Windows Phone internet browser by going to https://sub.mysite.com/mypage.php?param=value but for the likes of me I cannot get it to work with my app.

Now I should mention that the server has a self-signed certificate which I have included with my application and at first start up I prompt the user to install the certificate using:

```
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("server.cer"));
```

This seems to work fine because after the certificate is installed Internet Explorer on the device does not warn me about an uncertified certificate anymore.

The thing is though that trying to access the server via either WebClient or WebRequest both give me this error:

`An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\System.debug.resources.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_DisplayClasse.b_d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_DisplayClass1.b_0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at HttpsDing.MainPage.client_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)`

The implementation for both of them though work fine when accessing a normal site like http://bing.com or even https://bing.com.

The code for the webclient method is:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://sub.mysite.com"));
client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
```

And the code for the webrequest is:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.IO.Stream> GetRequestStreamAsync(this System.Net.WebRequest wr)
    {
        if (wr.ContentLength < 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The ContentLength property of the WebRequest must first be set to the length of the content to be written to the stream.");
        }

        return Task<System.IO.Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(wr.BeginGetRequestStream, wr.EndGetRequestStream, null);
    }

    public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this System.Net.WebRequest wr)
    {
        return Task<System.Net.WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(wr.BeginGetResponse, wr.EndGetResponse, null);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
await AuthenticateAsync();
```

This is all rather confusing to me, any ideas?

Comment: *I think this question was just asked very recently -- but can't find it.* You can't use self-signed certs in an application (which is different than the IE browser experience). They need to be signed by a cert-authority.

Comment: @WiredPrairie well that's a bit ridiculous, I hope someone has some contradictory information...